# Convert Oracle USING Query to JPA or JPQL?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

How to convert below query to Spring Data JPA or JPQL query ?

```
SELECT * FROM ACCT_PRCSS_DATA JOIN ACC_CUST_MSTR USING (ACC_NUM);
```

I tried below

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM EdsPrcssData e JOIN  ", nativeQuery = true)
List<ACCTPRCSSDATA> findByAccNum();
```

I also dont see any relationship between those two? Is this possible to fit into JPQL or native query ?

Added

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCT_PRCSS_DATA")
public class AcctPrcssData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ACCT_PRCSS_DATA_ID")
    private BigDecimal acctPrcssDataId;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="LST_ACTVY_DT")
    private Date lstActvyDt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="LST_UPDT_DT")
    private Date lstUpdtDt;

    @Column(name="LST_UPDT_USER_ID")
    private String lstUpdtUserId;

    @Column(name="ACCT_NUM")
    private BigDecimal acctNum;

    @Column(name="STAT_CD")
    private BigDecimal statCd;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AcctSrcData
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ACCT_SRC_DATA_ID")
    private AcctSrcData acctSrcData;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your entity class i.e ACCTPRCSSDATA, what do you meant by there is no relationship?

Comment: asaik if there is no relation between the two tables, you cannot do it